# How to properly print a table

Tags: list-manipulation, printing

to bootstrap my experience with Mathematica I'm trying to use it to print a table of values where the columns are different trigonometric functions and the rows contain different the values of said trig functions at some fixed angles that are between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ .

After studying the basics I came up with this lines of code

```
vec = Prepend[Table[Pi/i, {i, Reverse[Range[2, 11]]}], 0];
res = Map[#, vec] & /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot};
TextGrid [res, Frame -> All]
```

and the output is

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & \frac{1}{2} & \sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1 \\
 1 & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{5}{8}} & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} & \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{5}} & 1 & \sqrt{3} & \text{ComplexInfinity} \\
 \text{ComplexInfinity} & \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \sqrt{5}+1 & \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & 2 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & 1 \\
 1 & \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{5}{8}}} & \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & \sqrt{5}-1 & \sqrt{2} & 2 & \text{ComplexInfinity} \\
 \text{ComplexInfinity} & \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right) & \sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}+5} & \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right) & \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) & \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\
\end{array}$

the problems with this output are :

- some cells are in what it looks like a rational / expected form and others have a "weird" unevaluated form like $sin(\frac{\pi}{11})$ ; what is the problem with the latter ?
- I haven't found a way to print legends for the rows and the columns ( angle values and function names )

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "print legends" would it suffice to simply prepend your column / row values to `res`? Also that unevaluated form is simply the exact form for the expression. If it knows the exact ratio or whatever it'll return that, but otherwise Mathematica has a principle of remaining as exact and symbolic as possible.

Comment: @MB1965 basically any solution that could help me recognize rows and columns without making a mess with too much intricacies in the code . I would like to keep the computation separate from the the graphical layout . Regarding the 2nd part : can I force an approximation for the entire table ?

Comment: Second part, use `N`. That's its purpose. First part, isn't bad either. We'll do a bit of prepending. I'll knock you up a quick solution and explanation.

Comment: @MB1965 thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we'll just prepend your labels or whatever onto your grid. Note that you can change the dividers for `Grid` based constructs too, if you want a different appearance.

Here are my changes:

- Use `Through` to build your `res` in the transposed orientation
- Use `N` on that to get the numerical approximations you wanted
- Use `Prepend` to stick on the function labels, transpose the grid, then
  prepend on the number labels.

Looks like this in the end:

```
vec = Prepend[Table[Pi/i, {i, Reverse[Range[2, 11]]}], 0];
ops = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot};
res = Through@*ops /@ vec // N;
grid = Prepend[Transpose@Prepend[res, ops], Prepend[vec, Null]];
NumberForm[TextGrid[grid, Frame -> All], 3]
```

[image: fig grid]

A few things to note:

I use `@*` (`Composition`) to make `Through` apply after the functions and `NumberForm` to make sure the numerical approximations only display up to 3 digits.

Comment: @MB1965 I get the same result for `res` using `Through[ops[#]] & /@ vec // N.` I am not sure I understand the construct that you use for `res`. Can you enlighten me as to the differences, pros, cons? Thank you.

Comment: @JackLaVigne do you mean the `Composition (@*)`? What you did is another way to do it, but `&` is a very low precedence operator and so can often grab much more than what you intended. It just allows me to not have to use a pure function and is often clearer, in my mind.

Comment: @MB1965 Yes, the `Composition`. I see that it produces the desired result but can't quite figure out what is going on. Maybe you can spell it out for me?

Comment: @JackLaVigne I'd be happy to. `f@*g` in `FullForm` is `Composition[f,g]` and `Composition[f,g][h]` is `f[g[h]]`. Contrast that to `f@g` where we would get `f[g][h]`. It allows `f` to apply after `g` has applied instead of applying to `g` before hand. There is a corresponding head, `RightComposition /*` that is similar, but acts in reverse. Check out the docs for a more thorough treatment.

Comment: @MB1965 Got it. `Map[Composition[Through, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot}], {x, y, z}]` produces `{{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Csc[x], Sec[x], Cot[x]}, {Sin[y], Cos[y], 
  Tan[y], Csc[y], Sec[y], Cot[y]}, {Sin[z], Cos[z], Tan[z], Csc[z], 
  Sec[z], Cot[z]}}`. Thank you for the help.